# Erro : ArrayBuffer is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Bom dia a todos, estou utilizando `html2canvas` e `jsPDF` para exportar uma `div` para PDF, está funcionando no Google Chrome, firefox e no IE 11, mas nas versões 9 e 10 do IE está sendo exibida a seguinte mensagem :

**Erro**

> ArrayBuffer is undefined

**CÓDIGO:**

```
//função js que gera o PDF
function gerarPDF(relatorio)
{

     //atribuo meu relatorio a VARIAVEL form
     var form = $(relatorio);

     //crio a variavel da largura do meu relatorio
     var cache_width = form.width();

    //crio a variavel com a LARGURA & ALTURA de uma pagina A4
     var a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  

     //chamo a função get canvas que tira o print da minha tela
     getCanvas(form).then(function(canvas){

         var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

         //largura da IMG
         var imgWidth = 210; 


         //altura da pagina
         var pageHeight = 295;  


         //altura da imagem é igual a altura do canvas * largura da imagem / pela largura do canvas
         var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

         //tamanho restante = altura da imagem
         var heightLeft = imgHeight;

         var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

         var position = 0;

         doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

         heightLeft -= pageHeight;

         while (heightLeft >= 0) {

           position = heightLeft - imgHeight;

           doc.addPage();

           doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

           heightLeft -= pageHeight;

         }

         doc.save('relatorioOrcadoRealizado.pdf');
         form.width(cache_width);


     });
}

function getCanvas(divExportada){
 //CONVERTE a divExportada PARA CANVAS
 return html2canvas(divExportada,{
     imageTimeout:2000,
     removeContainer:true
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode verificar em [tabelas de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), no Internet Explorer 9 e anteriores, `ArrayBuffer` simplesmente não existe.
Já no 10, você não deveria estar recebendo esse erro.

Se você tiver problemas com versões arcaicas de navegadores, sempre verifique a compatibilidade das funcionalidades que você está usando. O [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=typed%20arrays) é muito bom para isso.